# Which is the best IDE to use with the Yii Framework

Tags: ide, yii

I have been using the Zend Studio for quite somewhile for my Zend projects and am looking for an IDE that would work well with Yii Framework.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yii is just PHP. So any IDE for PHP will work fine.

I use Eclipse. If you include the framework correctly you get all of the hints and code completion benefits. I like step-through debugging and breakpoints with Xdebug, which is why I use an IDE instead of Emacs/Vim/Notepad++, but they would work just fine too.

I don't know how integrated Zend Studio is with the Zend Framework, but it should work just fine for Yii development. Don't make life harder for yourself by learning a new environment. Save time and jump in with Zend. Again: **any PHP 5 IDE will work just fine for Yii, the best one is the one you are most familiar with!** ;)

Comment: thoroughly agree with 'the best is the one you are most familiar with' I myself used a combination of vim and notepad++ :P

Comment: +1 Eclipse with PDT and XDebug

Comment: I have actually been using PHPStorm lately and it rocks (but it's not free)

Comment: This is purely a opinion. Different IDEs can have different features. Also support for PHP frameworks vary with IDEs. For example NetBeans may have better auto-completion feature than Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a good number of people on the [Yii boards](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=IDE&type=forum) using NetBeans as the preferred IDE (as well as a lot of discussion regarding the topic of IDEs).

Here is a wiki post on how to make the most out of your Yii/NetBeans development environment:  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/83/

Update:

NetBeans 7.3 now has an community supported plugin for Yii which has some great features:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/47246/php-yii-framework-netbeans-phpcc

And is openly developed on github:
https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-yii-plugin/issues

Answer (score 4):

I recommend NetBeans as it gives you autocompletion of variables as well as PHPDOC comments, and a whole lot of other goodies. :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is any IDE made to work with Yii (like Zend Studio supports Zend Framework). On [Yii Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=IDE) page you can find a way to configure IDE to work with Yii framework better, and choise there is limited to [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDEs (last one seems to be not free). You can take a look at that wiki page as well as at IDEs description and see which IDE provides easier way to code, framework integration, debug etc. and make your decision.

Comment: To add to his response, coming from a Visual Studio Pro IDE which costs about $900, I would have to say what is offered with NetBeans / YII is really nice for free.  I was able to do what I needed and more. Just make sure you read the install instructions so that you include the correct paths to get full intellesense (or their name for it)

Answer (score 2):

As it's said before the NetBeans is good, but also if you like something more lightweight then go for vim or emacs.

Comment: Netbeans is good, but there is some code hints that not reads by Netbeans like `Yii::app()->user`. I didn't sure if other IDE also like this.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nusphere phpEd, code autocompletion & navigation by ctrl+click on class/method name works great for Yii.

Advice to improve IDE intelligence:
White DocBlock comments with @var ClassName.
For example:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;/**@var CClientScript */
```

Also if you include Yii from external directory to your project, you can specify it in project settings of Nusphere phpEd.

I prefer phpEd because it's written not on Java (fast!), have great degugger (not xdebug) + profiler and nice, aesthetically beautiful interface.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy using Netbeans, it just feels right. However I found setting up debugging and unit testing was a bit of a pain. I recently had to reinstall my computer so am giving Zend Studio 8 a try, the debugging, and profiling (I use Zend Server) are very good and require little to no setting up. However it doesn't feel as nice as Netbeans, not quite as polished maybe... it's hard to explain. Zend does have some very good features and ties in with Zend Server, however some of the other configuration options are very complex. Seems to be too many options at times, whilst Netbeans keeps it simple.

In an ideal world Netbeans would come with debugging, unit testing etc build in as I want to make websites not set up servers. I think it's part of the problem with some open source/free software, they require a bit of a learning curve or willingness to manually configure settings - it's understandable they are free. But it also holds back their more main stream acceptance. Sorry, that was a little off topic at the end!

Answer (score 0):

Can use eclipse with PDT + [Yiiclipse](http://yiiclipse.maziarz.org). Yiiclise adds wizard for creating new yii application (with initializiation of one of the demo application). But the most cool feature is Navigation. Now one can easily navigate between render methods and appropriate views, between widget method and widget source. Really useful.